# What are some programming languages/environments for kids that are actually good?

Tags: programming-languages, language-comparisons

Looking for software or an online resource that:

- Teaches programming, with kids in mind
- Has a nice, appealing modern look, not 1995-style
- Works on multiple platforms, not just Windows
- Is not someone's PhD thesis
- Is not itself written in Java
- Is either free or otherwise is so good that I'd pay for it

Comment: Since when is the implementation language relevant for the users?

Comment: On a machine that has less than 16 Gigs of RAM, Java Apps might run a bit sluggish. :)

Comment: @delnan: since the time Java was invented ;)

Answer (score 4):

Consider [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/), a slick beginner-oriented programming environment for the iPad.

From their description:

> Codea for iPad lets you create games and simulations — or just about any visual idea you have. Turn your thoughts into interactive creations that make use of iPad features like Multi-Touch and the accelerometer.
>
> We think Codea is the most beautiful code editor you'll use, and it's easy. Codea is designed to let you touch your code. Want to change a number? Just tap and drag it. How about a color, or an image? Tapping will bring up visual editors that let you choose exactly what you want.
>
> Codea is built on the Lua programming language. A simple, elegant language that doesn't rely too much on symbols — a perfect match for iPad.

Comment: Judging from what people write on their forums, Codea itself doesn't introduce you into programming like Hackety does. Looks nice other than that.

Comment: (It does include some nice examples and convenient access to documentation, though, which might be just as good as a fully-guided tutorial, depending on preferred learning style.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Hackety Hack](http://hackety.com/). It's Ruby, it's meant for kids, the UI is clean and nice and available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: Big big thank you! My son's having fun with Hackety Hack now :)

Comment: The tutorial texts are pretty straightforward but regardless of who reads them - you or your child - they do require some basic undertsnaindg of how the world works, i.e. what are instructions and why they are different from e.g. the shopping list. My son is 8, but a younger kid might be fine too. But we'll see how he progresses, he's just started! ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Kodu](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/kodu/) ?

It is not a programming-language *per se*, runs on XBox, but it could be interesting...

Comment: Looks interesting even though it's for game programming and yes, unfortunately it's XBox only.

Comment: As of this writing it has a desktop version [Kodu Game Lab](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10056]) or a Windows 8 Version one can download in the windows 8 store.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/). It uses a dialect of Scheme, and the accompanying teaching materials ("How to Design Programs" and "Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation") are well-written.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better ones I have come across is [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/). It may meet most of your criteria. It also has a large user base.

Comment: Yes, tried Scratch already: it looks awful, doesn't teach anything, and it's an academic research project. My son didn't like it (neither did I).

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time finding something that isn't an academic research project out there.  Most of the stuff for "kids in computing" is research oriented and highly experimental.

Comment: I have taught several classes to 10 - 12 year olds using Scratch and they love it. It is easy to construct working programs, they can quickly see the results and it does teach basic programming concepts such as variables, flow control, loops, objects and so on. I had an 8 year old in class once that also took to it. Some of the past students went on to create games in this system.

Answer (score 0):

I let my 8 year old play with python and that works even on modest machines well.

There really is a turtle equivalent here http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html which reassembles to old logo stuff you might remember.

He is - as I am - not a native english speaker, but I made him a list that translates the most important commands and he is happy.

python is real world stuff and sees, maybe even learns real world concept with easy syntax.

If you want a tutorial, there are some around, take a look at this: http://www.briggs.net.nz/snake-wrangling-for-kids.html

Answer (score 0):

**Scratch (MIT, 2007)**

[image]

> “As young people create and share Scratch projects, they learn
>   important mathematical and computational ideas, while also learning to
>   think creatively, reason systematically, and work collaboratively.”

- Shortcomings include the inability to create functions and abstractions.  Kids never see code.

**Alice (Carnegie Mellon, 1999)**

[image]

> “Alice is a modern programming environment designed to be a student's
>   first exposure to object-oriented programming. It allows students to
>   learn basic computer science while creating animated movies, simple
>   video games, where students control the behavior of 3D objects and
>   characters in a virtual world.”

- Shortcomings include being complete pre-built, it's not extensible.

**Android App Inventor (Google, 2010)**

[image]

> “App Inventor is a new tool in Google Labs that makes it easy for
>   anyone—programmers and non- programmers, professionals and students—to
>   create mobile applications for Android-powered devices.”

- Shortcomings include requirement of Google account and kids can't see code (it's Scheme!).

Comment: An awful creation that doesn't even show the code. I deleted it after 5 minutes of playing with it. Counterintuitive, doesn't invite to learning, has a disgusting GUI. For kids? Really?

Comment: Scratch v2.0 has facility to create new types of "blocks" and hence does support abstraction. However, these days, I have a different opinion of what abstraction is when it comes to kids.

Answer (score 0):

Code academy can be great, although doesn't allow for much experimentation, it teaches the concept needed. It teaches a variety of languages that should suit whatever your son wants to learn. If I or any other user helped, be sure to accept and up vote their answer!

[Code academy link](http://www.codecademy.com/)

-Harry